# Custom installer with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer

I need to create an installer for my application that is a Windows Service.

I want this installer check if the windows service is running before  install it. and also check some SQL Server queries.

The problem is...I don't know how to execute an pre-install code in Visual Studio Installer. I'm using VS 2017

I want run a code that will check this queries and if the there is a service running before install or upgrade the Windows Service.

How can I add a custom Installer with C# code logic in the VS 2017?

Comment: I would look into using inno setup, it will do everything you have said you need.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called "Custom Actions".

Right Click your VS Installer Project > View > Custom Actions.

This will allow you to execute any code that you like under the context of a variety of installer actions.

Comment: Yes, I see it.

but, how can I add the .cs to the custom action?

Comment: Your code will be in an assembly in your installer, either one dedicated to your CAs, or with your existing logic.vbs and js is also allowed.